# facebook application running

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to automatically run a facebook application in the background the time when the user is logged into his/her account ??

I have heard normal applications accepted by the user dosent work until they are in it. In the sense the user has approved to use the application but he/she is not using it.

so i wanted to know weather the application can be automatically run as the user logins ??

does facebook allow this method of use???

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do such activity. But would you like to tell what do you want to do by doing this? May be facebook is having any other way to accomplish your job.......